# Angular material animation for adding element to the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Hi using [Angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.autocomplete) and have list that is populated with list elements. On click of a button, I am adding one more element to the list at the beginning of it. I want to show a transition/animation while it is added to the list, so that it is clearly visible to the user that there a new list-item that is added.

I was not able to find out if there is something that Angular Material provides to make this happen. I have been through the documentation and demos provided on their website. How do I show the animation? Please help.

Comment: I think you have to use.
https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: @PareshGami Thanks, but I was looking of there was any alternatives that was more of google material theme.

Comment: I cannot get you exact what you say

Answer (score 0):

Angular-material requires [ngAnimate](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ngAnimate) which you can use to do what you want. If you have a `md-list` you probably bind your model with [ngRepeat](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) which supports `enter`, `leave` and `move` animations: [ngRepeat#animations](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations). You can use this to animate new elements being added to your model.

If this doesn't help you then you need to provide a code sample with plunkr/codepen or the like.